# Redirect to same page after form submit in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I wrote my own WordPress Plugin and I am trying to just refresh the page after form submit.

My code looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_admin_url();?>admin-post.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_nl">
    <input type="text" name="nl_title" placeholder="Title"> 
    <textarea type="text" name="nl_text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_nl">  
</form>
```

If I submit the form everything works fine. I get an Email with the right data, but I get redirected to a white page: to https://www.myurl.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php! Now I would need a hook or something similar to redirect to my plugin page again.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find the right solution - god knows why.

Thank you.

Comment: One way is like that you have to empty the form action tag and write code for submitted data in functions.php file. So after submission you directly redirect to your plugin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have send, save your date you should the function [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) from the WP API to redirect to your page. A source example below.

```
wp_safe_redirect(
    // Sanitize.
    esc_url(
        // Retrieves the site url for the current site.
        site_url( '/wp-admin/admin-post.php' )
    )
);
exit();
```

You see this usage [here in this repo](https://github.com/bueltge/adminimize/blob/519791aba96d51a324dea2cb9c2134fdb16e034c/inc-setup/import.php#L81) in a function to import data from a json string in the database in the full context.

Comment: I didn't thought of the simple and logic way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much. Have already read about it and fixed it in my file. I have another question: Now that I am redirecting, how can I achieve that a success message is displayed? Redirect with a GET Value in the URL? Or do you have a better way/idea? Thank you!

Comment: @AliElkhaiat I like to use transients to achieve that.  It's a built in WordPress session API.  However, I prefer to use AJAX rather than POST method of submitting forms.

Comment: A get value is an solution, use [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to use this via API.

Comment: It is not redirecting to the original page..it is redirecting to `/wp-admin/admin-post.php`.